# How to open a file with ".plotly" extension

Tags: python, plotly

I downloaded a file that I created on the interactive toolbox of the [Copernicus website](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/home) on climate.

I is saved  with this extension: `".plotly"`

How to open it - so that I can view it as a picture?

This is the content of the file:

```
{"data": [{"mode": "lines+markers", "x": ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-10", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-12", "2019-01-13", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-17", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-19", "2019-01-20", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-22", "2019-01-23", "2019-01-24", "2019-01-25", "2019-01-26", "2019-01-27", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-29", "2019-01-30", "2019-01-31"], "y": [1.986506462097168, 1.139273762702942, -0.1418689787387848, -0.714171290397644, -0.4602118134498596, -0.2752906382083893, -0.5288987755775452, -0.7405713796615601, -0.7374019622802734, -0.5999566912651062, -0.5094485878944397, 0.10179024189710617, 1.217246174812317, 1.4535152912139893, 0.9326292872428894, 0.5662962198257446, 0.9379780888557434, 0.3954199254512787, -0.06783988326787949, -0.23851798474788666, -0.8703995943069458, -1.6232084035873413, -0.9794990420341492, -0.9441877007484436, -0.7926209568977356, -0.014816214330494404, -0.14320173859596252, -0.06497668474912643, 0.49699893593788147, 0.4733152687549591, 0.7467145919799805], "type": "scatter", "uid": "ceb1c461-59bb-48e9-bfcc-63396d23a3c9"}], "layout": {"yaxis": {"title": {"text": "Near-Surface Air Temperature anomaly (K)"}}, "xaxis": {"title": {"text": "time"}}}}
```

Comment: You seem to have a `json` file. What do you mean by "_How to open it?_", namely, what do you plan to do with the data inside that file?

Comment: I want to view it as a picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you've is a [Plotly JSON chart schema](https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/json-chart-schema/#a-simple-example) and can be translated to many different languages, including [python](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/):

> *Translations of the JSON schema for practical use in several languages
>   are also available*:
>
> `Python`: [https://plot.ly/python/reference/](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/)
>   `R`: https://plot.ly/r/reference/
>   `MATLAB`: https://plot.ly/matlab/reference/
>   `JavaScript`: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/

---

Answering directly to your question, you can use the [Plotly JSON chart schema](https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/json-chart-schema/#a-simple-example) (`json`) file on `python` as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import json

with open("filename.plotly") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

fig = go.Figure(data=config['data'], layout=config['layout'])
fig.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - weirdly enough nothing shows up, either in Spyder or Pycharm, but there is also no error message when I run this snippet. The fig variable shows  data, x axis and y axis values ... . Jst nothing shows up.

Comment: It must be an IDE related problem because I've tested the code on `IntelliJ IDEA` and windows cmd line and it worked as expected.